# Select value from "option value" select

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, html-select

Hope someone can help as this is a new one on me.

I'm trying to extract the "option value" from a particular location.
E.g. in the example below, I want to get the 2.0000 from "Ashton".

The HTML is

```html
<div class="store-stock-select">
 <select name="storestock" id="storestock" onchange="showMessage()">
         <option value="">Check Store Stock</option>
                 <option value="2.0000">Ashton</option>
                        <option value="1.0000">Ballymena</option>
                        <option value="0.0000">Banbridge</option>
                        <option value="2.0000">Bangor</option>
                        <option value="0.0000">Bedford</option>
                        <option value="1.0000">Belfast</option>
                        <option value="1.0000">Blyth</option>
                        <option value="0.0000">Bolton</option>
                        <option value="0.0000">Bridgwater</option>
                        <option value="1.0000">Bristol</option>
```

...and the VBA I've tried so far is

```
    Set dropOptions = HTML.getElementsByTagName("select")
    For Each o In dropOptions.Options
        If o.innertext = "Ashton" Then sh01.Cells(r, 5) = o.Value
    Next
```

But to no avail. :(

If anyone could help me with this I would be so very grateful.
Thank you in advance.

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors

```
HTML.querySelector("#storestock option + option[value]").value
```

Also,

```
HTML.querySelectorAll("#storestock option").item(1).Value
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr but sh01.Cells(r, 5) = HTML.querySelector("#storestock option + option[value]").Value is not bringing anything back.  I also tried sh01.Cells(r, 5) = HTML.getElementById("storestock").Item(1).Value but still blank.  Ian.

Comment: Unfortunately both options brought back a blank.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying https://www.jollyes.co.uk/3-row-heavy-chain-collar-size-options-available.html

Comment: No no no ... sorry my bad.  Their was no stock available for that item.  I tried it for another item & that did work.  Thanks so much QHarr.  And apologies for the misunderstanding.  Thank you.i.

Comment: like a charm. Thank you.  I have an error handler in my vba to move to the next line on error. So no Ashton, it just moved on.  When I cycled through other items in the shop I started getting values.  - Thanks again.